# Yii CActiveDataProvider returns wrong data

Tags: php, yii, pdo, dataprovider, yii-components

I'm using 2 tables with 1 to many relation: campaign and group

This code returns only the relevant campaigns in the group.

```
 $models = Campaigns::model()->with(array(
                    'Campgroupassoc' => array('condition' => "groupid=$id"),
                ))->findAll();
```

while this code:

```
 $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Campaigns', array(
            'criteria' => array(
                'with' => array(
                    'Campgroupassoc' => array(
                        'condition' => "groupid=$id"
                    )
                ),
            )
        ));
```

returns campaigns which are not in the same group..

What am i doing wrong?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

```
'Campgroupassoc' => array(
                    'condition' => "groupid=:id",
                    'params'=>array(':id'=>$id)
                )
```

Also it is better to specify to what model the `groupid` belongs to. And of course you can see what SQL dataprovider is generating and analize it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit-----

After consulting with the Yii live chat, i found that even when using eager loading it will result in 2 queries instead of 1...

in order to solve this you need to add:

```
'together' => TRUE
```